# How can I read an excel file inside of a zip using PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, zip, phpspreadsheet

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    if (isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
            
            echo "the zip archive has been opened <br>";

            $desiredFileName = "Week1_2019.xlsx";
     
            if ($zip->locateName($desiredFileName) !== false) {

                echo "the zip file has been located <br>";
                
                $full_path = "zip://$file#$desiredFileName";

                try {
                    $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($full_path);
                } catch (PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Error loading file: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse excel files within a zip file using PhpSpreadsheet. Currently this is my output:

```
the zip archive has been opened
the zip file has been located
Error loading file: File "zip://C:\xampp\tmp\php4229.tmp#Week1_2019.xlsx" does not exist.
```

I have also tried supplying the raw file name as a string i.e $desiredFileName which throws the same exception: Error loading file: File "Week1_2019.xlsx" does not exist.

```php
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($desiredFileName);
```

Comment: Try closing the zip before calling `IOFactory::load()`.